# Check 2 tables, if match then update third table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that have data in them, due to the size of the third table I don't want to run queries against it so I have created a secondary table with only product SKU and IDs.

Here is what I am trying to do but I am quite confused on where to start.

Optimistically there is a way to do this with a MySQL query and loop through all of the records.

```
if wp_stc_outofstock `product_number` == wp_stc_current_products `sku`
    
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE post_id = 'wp_stc_outofstock.product_number' AND meta_key = '_stock_status'
```

Any help is appreciated, I am sure I am not doing a great job explaining it.

Comment: "I don't want to run queries" - why? If its performance maybe that can be fixed rather than de-normalization. A [multi table update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) can do this sort of thing.

Comment: Hello, well its a wordpress wp_postmeta and its millions of rows, the idea was just using the other tables that have indexed columns to execute the base query very quickly.

Comment: Also see [Index WP MySQL For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: If you cant answer the question whats the point of responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best attempt given your limited explanation -

```
UPDATE `wp_stc_outofstock` `oos`
JOIN `wp_stc_current_products` `cp`
    ON `oos`.`product_number` = `cp`.`sku`
JOIN `wp_postmeta` `pm`
    ON `oos`.`product_number` = `pm`.`post_id`
    AND `pm`.`meta_key` = '_stock_status'
SET `pm`.`meta_value` = 'outofstock';
```

As @danblack suggested, perhaps you should be dealing with your performance concerns, particularly by looking at your indexing. As long as the tables are indexed appropriately, millions of rows is not an issue.

Comment: This is very cool, I will decode it in my head and try. I understand the thought. I got it to work by using the standard wp query and it took minutes, I was thinking this method could take under a second. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I was able to alter it a bit to make it work for me, I know I was vague, sorry about that. It is down from ~30 seconds to 6.6 seconds, I will work on it a bit more to knock down the time. Thank you!

```UPDATE `wp_stc_outofstock` `oos`
JOIN `wp_postmeta` `pm`
JOIN `wp_stc_current_products` `cp`
    ON `oos`.`product_number` = `cp`.`sku`
SET `pm`.`meta_value` = 'outofstock'
WHERE post_id = `cp`.`product_id` AND meta_key = '_stock_status'; ```

Comment: 6.6 seconds is still very slow. You should look at the link provided by @danblack.

Comment: Thanks @nnichols I did try that plugin and it actually went from 6.6 seconds to 20.4 seconds.